# Setting cookie on an iframe website with ngx-cookie-service

Tags: angular, cookies, iframe, angular-cookies, ngx-cookie-service

When I embed a youtube video for example in my angular component:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/w3jLJU7DT5E"></iframe></div>
```

I will get two entries in my Application/Storage/Cookies in Developer console:

[image]

One is my storage for my `localhost` and the other one is for iframe website.

Using [ngx-cookie-service](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-cookie-service) I tried to set a cookie into youtube section like this:

```
this.cookieService.set('cookie1', 'cookie1-value', null, null, 'https://youtube.com');
```

by setting only `name`, `value` and `domain` since `.set` is defined like this: `set( name: string, value: string, expires?: number | Date, path?: string, domain?: string, secure?: boolean, sameSite?: 'Lax' | 'Strict' | 'None' ): void;`

but it sets it into my `https://localhost:4200`.

**Is it event possible to set it into `https://youtube.com` section?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing that I was trying to achieve is `XSS` or `Cross-site scripting` and it would be only possible to do if the domain in `iframe` was the same as the parent domain.